# Convergence of power of EDF: $F(x_n)^n \to 1 \overset{?}{\implies} \hat F_n(x_n)^n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow} 1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

**Situation**

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. random variables on a shared probability space, with distribution function $F$.

Denote the empirical distribution function (EDF) as $\hat F_n(\cdot) := \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1\{X_i \leq \cdot\}$.

Suppose we have a sequence $x_m \uparrow \infty$ such that $F(x_m)^m \to 1$ as $m \to \infty$.

Additionally, let $m \equiv m_n = o(n)$ with $m_n \to \infty$.

**Question**

Does it follow that
$$\hat F_n(x_m)^m \to 1$$
in any sense (almost surely, in probability, ...) as $n \to \infty$?

---

**Thoughts**

It would be nice to have a.s. convergence, but I think the answer is no. Here's my attempt so far:

Suppose that $\hat \Omega$ is a set with $\mathbb P(\hat \Omega) = 1$ and $\|\hat F_n^\omega - F\|_\infty \to 0$ for all $\omega \in \hat \Omega$. (Glivenko-Cantelli tells us this is possible.) Let $\omega \in \hat \Omega$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrarily small.

There exists $N_\omega^\varepsilon \in \mathbb N$ such that $\| \hat F_n^\omega - F \|_\infty \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N_\omega^\varepsilon$.

So we have for all $n \geq N_\omega^\varepsilon$
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 \leq 1 - \hat F_n^\omega(x_m)^m &\leq 1 - \big( F(x_m) - \varepsilon \big)^m \\
&= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} F(x_m)^{m-k} \cdot (-\varepsilon)^k \\
&= 1 - \Big[ F(x_m)^m + \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} F(x_m)^{m-k} \cdot (-\varepsilon)^k \Big] \\
&= \underbrace{ 1 - F(x_m)^m}_{\to 0} - \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} \cdot F(x_m)^{m-k} \cdot (-\varepsilon)^k
\end{aligned}
$$
So the issue is the "error term"
$$
\text{err} := - \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} \cdot F(x_m)^{m-k} \cdot (-\varepsilon)^k,
$$
which we need to vanish to achieve the desired limit.

But I don't see how to do that, after all,
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\text{err}| &\leq \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} \left| (-\varepsilon)^k \right| \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{m}{k} \varepsilon^k \\
&= (1 + \varepsilon)^m - 1
\end{aligned}
$$
As $n$ increases, so does $m \equiv m_n$, driving the right hand side up. On the other hand, higher $n$'s allow us to choose a smaller $\varepsilon$, driving the RHS back toward zero.

It seems that the speed of convergence (which determines the smallest $\varepsilon >0$ for the $n > N$) determines whether convergence is achieved.

**More information**

In the particular example I'm looking at we have

- $F(x) > 1 - \frac{c}{\log^\delta(x)}$ for large $x$, where $c>0$ and $\delta > 2$; and
- $x_m := \xi \cdot \text e^m$ for $\xi \in (0,1)$.

Maybe the specifics here are helpful.